# Maximizing Product of Distribution and Random Variable

Tags: probability, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

here my question:

Suppose $Y$ is a random variable distributed on $[0,1]$ accodring to cdf $F(Y).$ Assume cdf $F(Y)$ admits a differentiable density $f(Y).$ 
Let  $a \in [0,1]$ be a fixed parameter.
Is there any class of distributions or any further assumptions that guarantee that the following problem is concave:

$$\max F(y) (a-y)$$

where one maximizes over $y \in [0,1]$.

Comment: One shouldn't use the same symbol, in this case $y,$ to refer both to a random variable and to the argument to its c.d.f. Often one uses a capital $Y$ for the former and lower-case $y$ for the latter. The more serious problem is that I can't understand what you mean by "the following problem" or what the thing is that you want to be concave. What does $F(y\le x)$ mean? Might you mean $F(x),$ i.e. $\Pr(y\le x)\text{?}$

Comment: yes you are correct, edited.